# $_FILES["file"]["size"] in megabytes

Tags: file-upload, filesize

I'm using this part of a code to get variable size while uploading

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"]<1024)
{ //do something
}
```

But when I upload files that are more than 1mb it shows me that file size is 0. But it works when I upload files that are in bytes or kilobytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure these uploads are even successful? Maybe your upload_max_filesize is 1M, so files which are bigger than 1M aren't actually uploaded. Thats why you get the 0. just guessing...

Comment: It is set to 50M and I'm uploading 4mb

Comment: actually i think there is a limit and this might be interesting for you, it indicates the limit is really 1M: http://drupal.org/node/333833

Comment: It is fixed. I just updated upload_max_filesize and restarted xampp